# How to use signal of arrays in escher?

Tags: arrays, signals, julia, reactive

I am trying to use escher to build a UI. I am collecting input from the UI, the input are passed to my Julia program with map function as: `output = map(function, input1, input2)`

The function return an `array(Float64,1)`. when I visualize in the UI I get the following: `4-element Array{Float64,1}: 3.43632e5 3.63805e5 3.69266e5 3.71911e5`
I am trying to visualize one element at a time but I keep getting errors. It is as of I cant use `output[index]`.

when I apply enumerate(output), I get the following:

`Enumerate{Reactive.Signal{Array{Float64,1}}}(Signal{Array{Float64,1}}([343631.7211352585,363804.7393436705,369265.5843143601,371910.53794551373], nactions=0))`

Does any one have an idea how can I visualize the elements of my output. Sorry it is maybe evident for you but I have been looking and I didn't find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, I think you want

```
map(x->x[2], S)
```

where `S` is the `Signal` object. This will give you the second element in a way that will update automatically when `S` changes.

If you just want to extract the 2nd element, you can use `S.value[2]`, but this will (I believe) not update automatically.

EDIT: By the way, it is always more useful if you can provide a minimal working example to try these things out.

Comment: Thank you David! Your suggestions work! And indeed with S.value[2] there is no automatic update. Sorry for the missing example, next time I will provide an one (this is my first time posting on stackoverflow :S)